# adobe flex spellchecker for multiple language

Tags: apache-flex, spell-checking

I am trying to figure out the best way for doing spellcheck in flex application. 
I need a support of multiple languages, like: english, russian and so on. Also, I don't need a realtime spellchecking, only in some particular moment(for example, user click button: "check my text"). I found clientside solution here - [flex:SpellCheck](http://www.flextendibles.com/index.html) , but looks like it able to check only english text. So now I am thinking 
serverside solution, that recieve a text and needed language, check it(for example with aspell) and returns result. How do you think: is this a good way or I am missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the Squiglly project on Adobe Labs - [link](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/squiggly/)

Quoting the page:

> Squiggly is a
>   spell checking engine for Adobe®
>   Flash® Player and Adobe AIR®. The
>   Squiggly library allows you to easily
>   add spell checking functionality in
>   any Adobe Flex® 3 or Flex 4 based text
>   control. The distribution package
>   consists of a utility for building
>   your own spelling dictionaries, a
>   sample English dictionary [...]

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot! Looks very promising!

Comment: Oh, no! I found at adobe website:"

Important note: The spelling suggestion algorithm for this release is based on English phonological rules. As such, it should only be used with an English dictionary for checking English text. The plan is to address this limitation in a future release of this project."

So my question is back

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was actually using it with english. Other thing we've used on a project was http://www.gskinner.com/products/spl/about.php . It's a commercial component, I don't remember the actual pricing, and their sale site is offline at the moment.

Comment: anyway, thank you very much. It doesn't fit all my requirements, but also will be very helpful. Thank you!